# Django custom middleware executing twice

Tags: python, django

I am writing a middleware to track user activity by writing it to a file; the pages visited by him, the buttons clicked and so on and so forth. To test my middleware for now I am just writing a message to the file. But for some reason the message is being written twice to the file. And I am on django 1.11

Here is my **middleware:**

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
import datetime


class TodoappMiddleware(object):
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        f = open("--my file path--", 'a')
        date_and_time = datetime.datetime.now()
        f.write('\n')
        f.write(str(date_and_time))
        f.write('\tMiddleware successfully executed\n')
        f.close()

        response = self.get_response(request)

        return response
```

**EDIT:** Got to know that redirect causes middleware to execute twice.
Here are my views which use `HttpResponseRedirect`

```
def login_user(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        login_form = Login(request.POST)
        if login_form.is_valid():
            email = login_form.cleaned_data['email']
            password = login_form.cleaned_data['password']
            User.objects.get(email=email)
            user = authenticate(email=email, password=password)
            if user is not None:
                if user.is_active:
                    login(request, user)
                    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('dashboard'))
                else:
                    return HttpResponse("<h2>Waiting for admin to authenticate you</h2>")
        else:
            return render(request, 'registration/login.html', {'errors': login_form.errors})

    return render(request, 'registration/login.html', {'form': Login()})


@login_required
def logout_user(request):
    logout(request)
    return redirect('login_user')
```

What changes do I need to do so that the middleware is executed only once ?

Comment: which part of the page is being executed twice?  Is it all the `f.writes` or just one?

Comment: Everything. Before and after the request.

Comment: One reason would be if your middleware is listed twice. Please post the `MIDDLEWARE` setting. Another might be if you were using redirects, so that each request ended up as two requests.

Comment: Yeah you're right I am using `HttpResponseRedirect` to redirect the user to his account dashboard after a successful login. So what is the work around for it now ?

Comment: Well, what do you want to do? Most logging frameworks would indeed treat these as two separate requests. Or you could not log redirects, or you could choose one of various other rules. Please edit the question with this new information on redirects, and what your desired behavior is.

Comment: @Vai: If you're directing your comment at someone be sure to @-mention them in your comment. Otherwise they won't be notified.

Comment: @KevinChristopherHenry i am using the HttpResponseRedirect to redirect the user to his account dashboard on successful login and the same to redirect to the login view on successful logout. And I am using a custom middleware to track user activity; button clicks and all. I'll edit the question and add my views which contain the HttpResponseRedirect.

Comment: @KevinChristopherHenry Edited the question. Kindly help me out now.